# Get additional pairs of Gebel's Glasses in NG+?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

To obtain Gebel's Glasses, you need to have 100% shard completion. After getting 100%, a chest will appear in the transmutation circle by Johannes.

In my first playthrough, I had received this item. In my second NG+ playthough, I've reached the end of the game again but the chest isn't appearing this time.

**Can I still get another pair of Gebel's Glasses?**

Every other item so far I've been able to get another copy of (except for shards and other items that doesn't carry over). Are these glasses an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this chest will not spawn again anymore. After playing through at least three more replays, the chest never spawned again. It looks like you can only receive one of this item.